# Создание приложения для AR-очков в Android Studio на Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, vulkan, ar

Есть проект для AR-очков (Magic Leap 2). Нужно на него написать приложение на Kotlin (очень желательно). Нужны советы по setup'у проекта. Какие SDK установить, какая IDE нужна, и как вообще создать проект в этой IDE для AR-очков.

Вот эту доку читал, но что дальше делать не понял:
https://developer-docs.magicleap.cloud/docs/guides/native/getting-started/native-setup-overview/

Есть какой-то вариант использования Vulkan API с Kotlin/Native, но туториал 2019 года: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1288159/Vulkan-API-with-Kotlin-Native-Project-Setup#mingw

Comment: Тут же все написано, какие тулы установить и какую среду выбрать: https://developer-docs.magicleap.cloud/docs/guides/getting-started/

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja все сделал, создал проект Native C++ в Android Studio. Но дальше не двинулся, подскажите, пожалуйста, может знаете, как связать Application Simulator из Magic Leap 2 с Android Studio

Comment: Через ADB, как я понимаю: https://developer-docs.magicleap.cloud/docs/guides/developer-tools/android-debug-bridge/